# R graphing: Making two plots closer together on the graph

Tags: r, plot

I have a graph made with the code:

```
yvalue = c(100, -100, 50, 0)
xvalue = c(1, 1, 2, 2)
gmin = c(-100, 0)
gmax = c(100, 50)
xarrow = c(1, 2, 3, 4)
gplot = plot(xvalue, yvalue, xaxt="n", main="Just a graph", xlab="Groups", ylab="y-value")
xvaluenames = c("Group 1", "Group 2", 1, 2)
axis(1, at = 1:length(xvalue), labels = xvaluenames)
arrows(x0=xarrow, y0=gmin, x1=xarrow, y1=gmax, length=0)
abline(h=0)
```

[image: Graph]

I want Group 1 and Group 2 plots to be closer together.  More like:

[image: Better Graph]

Does anyone have advise on how to get them closer together?

Comment: change your x values and set the xlim argument in plot(). Also, since you don't have arrow heads, just use segments()

Comment: @tim riffe, I added type="n" in the plot() since I only need the bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an additional parameter to your `graph()` call you could add: `xlim = c(x1,x2)`, where `x1` and `x2` are the limits of your visible x-axis.

In your case, since you are using x-coords `1` and `2` you could use `xlim=c(0.5,2.5)`

[image]